# Why am I getting an attribute error when trying to use tf.compat.v1

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, single-shot-detector

I am getting this error while training my dataset on SSD:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "train_ssd_network.py", line 394, in <module>
     tf.compat.v1.app.run()
   File "C:\Users\X\.conda\envs\temp\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
     _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
   File "C:\Users\X\.conda\envs\temp\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 308, in run
     _run_main(main, args)
   File "C:\Users\X\.conda\envs\temp\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 254, in _run_main
     sys.exit(main(argv))
   File "train_ssd_network.py", line 204, in main
     global_step = slim.create_global_step()
   File "C:\Users\X\.conda\envs\temp\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\module_wrapper.py", line 193, in __getattr__
     attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name) AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator' has no attribute 'create_global_step'
```

line 394:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
```

I am using tf version 1.15.0 and I have chnaged all the `tf.` with `tf.compat.v1.` and it resolved most of my errors but I can't seem to understand how to resolve this one as this is in the super class.